# prometheus query same metric different label values last over time single time series

Tags: sum, prometheus, metrics

this prometheus query:

```
metric_xxx{task="task1"}
```

returns these metris:

```
metric_xxx{task="task1, task_uid="task1_202403051227"}
metric_xxx{task="task1, task_uid="task1_202403051323"}
metric_xxx{task="task1, task_uid="task1_202403051417"}
```

These give me 3 time series as it is same metric but its label task_uid is different because it is produces by separate execution.

I would like to take value of most recent metric and produce single time series.

How can I do it?

This query I tried so it gives me the shape but I do not want to sum.

```
last_over_time(sum(metric_xxx{task="task1"} and timestamp(metric_xxx{task="task1"}) == on() group_left() max(timestamp(metric_xxx{task="task1"})))[1h:1m])
```

I would like to achieve timeseries as in the attached picture.
[image]

Comment: It seems like you are using Pushgateway, and trying to workaround it's behaviour in part of storing pushed metric infinitely. Have you considered simply dropping `task_uid` from your data? Also, are you aware of performance impact of your data model?

Comment: I use argo workflows to expose these metrics. I could drop task_uid but i think there might be some label out of my control such as pod bramę with some id in it. Is it possible to exclude some labels during query so all metrics could be treated as same Metric without unique labels?

Comment: No Dariusz, this is not similar to my answer, where you left comment. You case (probably?) might be solved with somewhat structurally(!) similar query, but it should employ some other principles of the identifying "current" value.

Comment: I don't think you can drop label on the ingestion here. Every time series in Prometheus must have unique label set (name + values of the labels)

Comment: What would be your change suggestion if I may ask? Can you share some example please?

Comment: My suggestion is simple: clean your data before it is in the Prometheus. Details on how (or if) this possible differ depending of exporter. And I don't imply I know how (or if) this can be done for yours.